# FirefoxOS - Redirect path

Tags: javascript, firefox, path, oauth-2.0, firefox-os

today I'm developing an app for Firefox OS, but I have a problem. I would use the OAuth2 method for receiving the access token, but I don't know where redirect the page after the Authorization.
What is the path? There is any browser api that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a hosted app, then redirect to a URL on your domain just like you would in a browser. If it's a packaged app, declare [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#redirects) in your manifest. Your app must be [privileged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps#Privileged_app) to use this field.